# Django (1.4...) 'Pincode' decryption not working

Tags: python, django, encryption

I am working on a old / outdated webapp and helping bring it into the world of 2018.

The app is running on Django 1.4.19 and Python 2, both of which are slated to be upgraded to their newest LTS versions.

However, before this upgrade can begin we have to fulfil some GDPR / licensing requirements.

User can currently login to our app with both a password AND a 4 digit PIN-number. The PIN number is set on a `UserProfile` model, like so:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_PINCODE = '0000'
    PIN_VALIDATOR = RegexValidator(
        regex='^\d{4}$', message=_('Error message.'),
        code='invalid_pin')
    MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 4
    LOGIN_BLOCK_DURATION = timedelta(hours=1)

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    pincode = models.CharField(
        _('pin'), max_length=1000, null=True,
        blank=True, default=DEFAULT_PINCODE,
        validators=[PIN_VALIDATOR])
```

This is stored as a plain text and we want to hash/salt it as its saved in the database.

To do this I created the following methods.

```
def check_pin(self, raw_pincode):
    """
    :param raw_password:
    :return: a boolean that indicates whether the raw_pincode matches
    self.pincode
    """
    return check_password(raw_pincode, self.pincode)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.pincode = make_password(self.pincode)
    super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The latter method ensures the pincode is encrypted. This method required me to change the `pincode` field from a `IntegerField` to `CharField` and returns a large encrypted string, but it works - when I type a value in the admin and save I get a string like `pbkdf2_sha256$10000$MXyCQoqecmFt$kWEOpO8/GUk76ubB5wsR7Ry1v5WR30RMDQpytPTuyPY=`

However, the first method is giving me trouble.

On our `PinLoginForm` (under the '`def clean` method) I run the following code to validate the pin

```
    try:

        data['pin'] = pin

        print(self.user_profile.check_pin(pin))
        print(pin)
        print(self.user_profile.pincode)

        if self.user_profile.check_pin(pin) == False:
            raise KeyError

    except KeyError:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('Wrong pincode.'))
```

Here is the weird thing, this code only works the first time (directly after setting the pin in the admin) 
The print statements return

```
True
4444
pbkdf2_sha256$10000$NOMCsVFJHj3j$72dHZMVEuD6vGsjhPSw5cNY6eefRTwI1yfXrwUOkd/Q=
```

Yet when I logout and try again it states that my pin is incorrect, with the print statements providing the following output:

```
False
4444
pbkdf2_sha256$10000$wkGSA5kHnJPg$fO8BGkFe787ufKUoKMgwcBqg0VxBACf4FxT9lkwzTyU=
```

Its almost as if the pin has changes, but I did not change it. There are a number of packages that would solve my problem, but they either do not work on Django 1.4 (and we have to deploy this before we can continue upgrading) or python 3 (which will be our next upgrade), hence the 'manual'  approach.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Notice the difference in the second line...

Comment: In the save method you have a line "self.pincode = make_password(self.pincode)" . Are you re-encoding an already encoded pincode?

Comment: Hmm, the form is saving some value on the model. This might just be it!